# Remove element from String Array when another element starts with the same letter

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a String Array containing elements starting with a letter then a colon and then some random text. Example:

```
a = [
    "a:aushdad",
    "b:ofigjhld",
    "g:dkfgjdfg",
    "b:kjfdgkdfj"
]
```

I want to keep only the first element starting with `b:` and the same for any other duplicates there might be.

The end result should be:

```
a = [
    "a:aushdad",
    "b:ofigjhld",
    "g:dkfgjdfg",
]
```

How could this be achieved? Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```js
var a = [
    "a:aushdad",
    "b:ofigjhld",
    "g:dkfgjdfg",
    "b:kjfdgkdfj"
]

var letters = [];
var result = a.reduce(function(prev,current){
  if(letters.indexOf(current[0]) === -1) {
     letters.push(current[0]);
     prev.push(current);
  }
  return prev;
}, []);

console.log(result); // ["a:aushdad", "b:ofigjhld", "g:dkfgjdfg"]
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Much simpler than the other things I've tried. Thank you!

Comment: Happy to be of service. Thinking about this a bit more it might make more sense semantically to use filter instead of reduce, but the basic idea would remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/filter) from array.

```
//store already used 'key'
var map = {};

//regexp used to get the interesting part 
var regexp = /^.*?:/;

//function used for the filter, true add the value to the result array.
function myFilter(value){
    //get the key
    var key = regexp.exec(value)[0];

    //key not null and not used ?
    if(key && !map[key]){
        map[key] = true;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

var result = myArray.filter(myFilter);
```

Comment: This works well too, but I'm choosing Ray's answer because it's a bit simpler. But thank you!